# 64bit upgrade for .NET

Tags: c#, 64-bit, upgrade

Whats the best resource to look at for when migrating dotnet applications from 32bit to 64bit.

---

SIMILAR QUESTION

[Are there any considerations needed to be taken running your .net program on x64 vs x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145026/are-there-any-considerations-needed-to-be-taken-running-your-net-program-on-x64)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- This [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx) is useful.
- This [blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/tags/Writing+code+targeted+at+64bit_2E00_/default.aspx) has some good .NET 64-bit information.
- Run the built-in or standalone FxCop and fix all its 64-bit warnings, especially around P/Invoke.
- **EDIT:** Be careful [if you use IntPtr](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasics32bitAnd64bitConfusionAroundX86AndX64AndTheNETFrameworkAndCLR.aspx) in your code, or call into an x86 compiled assembly.

That's it, really. As long as you heed the FxCop warnings and also recompile your code (to avoid the 32-bit WOW layer), you should be fine.